# SwiftUI Changing Background Color

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

[image]
[image]

The first image shows the simulated application using Xcode
and the second image is a mockup design for the application.

Thus I want to change the background color as white and the list items as gray oppositely.

But, I tried tons of ways to set the backgrounds but none of them did not work correctly.
I just wanted to set the background color as white first, and I failed.

ListView.swift

```swift
struct ListView: View
{
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @EnvironmentObject var dateHolder: DateHolder

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \TaskItem.dueDate, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<TaskItem>

    var body: some View
    {
        NavigationView
        {
            VStack
            {
                ZStack
                {
                    List
                    {
                        ForEach(items)
                        { item in
                            NavigationLink(destination: EditTaskView(
                                passedTaskItem: item,
                                initialDate: Date())
                                .environmentObject(dateHolder))
                            {
                                Task(passedTaskItem: item)
                                    .environmentObject(dateHolder)
                            }
                        }
                        .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
                    }
                    .toolbar
                    {
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing)
                        {
                            EditButton()
                        }
                    }
                    
                    FloatingButton().environmentObject(dateHolder)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("To-Do List")
        }
    }
    
    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet)
    {
        withAnimation
        {
            offsets.map { items[$0] }.forEach(viewContext.delete)

            dateHolder.saveContext(viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```

Main.swift

```swift
@main
struct ToDoListApp: App {
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            let context = persistenceController.container.viewContext
            let dateHolder = DateHolder(context)
            
            ListView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
                .environmentObject(dateHolder)
        }
    }
}
```

These are swift codes that I'm using for this application.

Is there any solution that might resolve this situation?

Comment: In main.swift use a `ZStack` around your `ListView`. Put `Color.white.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` as the first item in the ZStack and then your list view

Comment: Thank you for your comment but it doesn't work.. I really want to know why the changing background color is this difficult and hard bruh

Comment: You also need to specify a `.background` modifier for your outermost view

Comment: Get rid of `List` which has tons of issues with background, and use a combination of `ScrollView { LazyVStack {` instead. You will still need to change background for each view, but this way there's no "hidden" issues with background

Comment: @rapiddevice Thank you it's working! now I need to make it asthetic cause ScrollView and LazyVStack don't have default design as List has